# Remove blank plot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, facet-grid

Another challenge I've dealing with, but no success... I have the following code:

```
x<-c(seq(1,10,0.5),seq(50,60,0.5))
y<-runif(40)
df<-data.frame(x,y)
df$gender<-c(rep(0,19),rep(1,21))
r<-c(runif(50,0,10),runif(20,50,60))
df_rug<-data.frame(r)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df,aes(x,y))+geom_line()+
  geom_rug(data = df_rug, aes(x = r, y = Inf), color = 'red', sides = 'b')+
  facet_grid(.~gender,scales = "free")
```

which produces the following plot:

[image]

I'm trying to remove the blank parts on the left panel (from x=10) and on the right panel (under x=50). I introduced the option `scales=("free")` that works perfectly without the `geom_rug()` option, but I need to keep the red ticks of `geom_rug()`. How can I cut the blank parts of each panel? I tried to explore the `element.blank()` option, with no success...

Comment: I wonder what your real data is that you are trying to plot...

Comment: I presented a simplifed version of the problem with simple data that can be easily reproduced by anyone who want to try to solve the problem ;-)

Comment: You're evading my question! Supplying two datasets with differing sizes to a plot makes me curious. I worry that you may be doing something, ... um, not quite right? But as long as it makes sense to you, I'll let it be.

Comment: Ok :-) So in my context, the `y` values represent the kernel density estimates of estimated eigenvalues of a matrix. The `x` values are a sequence of values between two extreme values generated according to the bandwidth. The `r` values are the true eigenvalues of the matrix. They consist of a large amount of values close to zero and a small amount of values close to `max(x)`. The idea is to plot the estimated density and compare it with the true eigenvalues (red ticks), separating the two groups of true eigenvalues. I already have all the values. My problem was just the plot  ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `ggplot2`, it's really hard to make discontinuous axis.

As, I understand your question, it seems that you have some rug values for gender = 0 and for gender = 1. If you add an extra column `gender` to your `df_rug`, you will be able to separate `rug` in function of `gender` as you are doing for `df` by using `facet_grid`:

```r
df_rug<-data.frame(r, gender = c(rep(0,50),rep(1,20)))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df,aes(x,y))+geom_line()+
  geom_rug(data = df_rug, aes(x = r, y = Inf), color = 'red', sides = 'b')+
  facet_grid(.~gender,scales = "free")
```

[image]

Does it answer your question ?

Comment: God...... So simple...... You are incredibly helpful today @dc37!!

Comment: Thank you very much one thousand million of times! :-) I use R for years but I'm always stuck for some problems and always learning! :-)

Comment: Same situations of you. That's maintain the fun alive !